# unwanted trigger of function in tr tag when clicking a button in row

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, angular-forms

i have a table with a button on each row.

```
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="accountDetails(user._id)">

                <td>{{user.firstName | titlecase}} {{user.lastName | titlecase}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.mobile}}</td>
                <td">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                    (click)="blockUnblock(user._id, 1)">UnBlock</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Here i have a click function in  tag and one also in  tag button.

I require to click on the row to execute accountDetails(), but on clicking the button also, the accountDetails() gets triggered alongwith blockUnblock().

how can i make the accountDetails() work, in rest of the row except on the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent propagation of the click event on parents by using [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

You can inline this method in your html in Angular:

```
(click)="blockUnblock(user._id, 1); $event.stopPropagation()"
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```